# Create folder when dir not exist cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a stupid problem but i don't know where i have error. My batch script:

```
    D:
    cd D:\Kafka\bin\windows
If exist D:\Kafka\test\dir\dir1 
( Echo "a" )
Else ( mkdir D:\Kafka\test\dir\dir1 )
```

I get a syntax error but i don't know where.

Comment: You don't need to check if the directory exists, just `M`ake the `D`irectory, if it already exists, you'll get an error message which you can simply send to the `NUL` device. e.g. `@MD "D:\Kafka\test\dir\dir1" 2> NUL`. Alternatively you should use the following syntax, `@If Not Exist "D:\Kafka\test\dir\dir1\" MD "D:\Kafka\test\dir\dir1"`, the trailing backslash will _usually_ designate `dir1` as a directory and not a file without extension. BTW, you can get rid of the first line, and change the second one to `CD /D "D:\Kafka\bin\windows"`.

Comment: If you read the help file for the `IF` command you will see the proper syntax you need to use for `IF...ELSE`.  The parentheses need to be on the same line as the ELSE.

Comment: Also you really do need to open up a Command Prompt window, type `if /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output usage information. It will show you that you are not placing your parentheses correctly. You can also do that with `cd /?`, to understand the reason why I made the earlier suggestion regarding your first two lines.

Comment: I read data from kafka server and it is in if clause only i don't write here. I have more complicated script but i needed help with this fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what did you mean by bot ?
anyway here is the syntax :

```
If exist "D:\Kafka\test\dir\dir1" ( 
    Echo "a"
) Else ( 
    mkdir "D:\Kafka\test\dir\dir1"
)
```